# If multiplication is not repeated addition what is it?

Tags: arithmetic

I always thought multiplication meant repeated addition. Consider

$$4 \times 3 = 12.$$

This the same as

$$4 + 4 + 4 = 12.$$

Now consider

$$\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}. $$

If I use repeated addition approach, then I get

$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1. $$

So the repeated addition approach doesn't really work.

I was helping my nephew with his maths homework and I was using the repeated addition approach. Then multiplying fractions came up and now I'm confused. Is there an easy answer to this?? Anything I could read. I'm very interested in trying to understand it. Right now it feels like I know nothing. lol

Comment: Multiplication is more of a scaling or stretching operation than repeated addition.  So when you multiply by $1/2$ you're really just shrinking everything down to half the size just as multiplying by $2$ doubles everything.

Comment: $\frac12\times\frac12$ would be addition of half copy of $\frac12$, not $2$ copies.

Comment: Multiplication is area. If you have a rectangle with four unit segments along along one side and three unit segments along another side, altogether  it consists of twelve squares altogether. If you have a rectangle with half of a unit segment along one side and a half of a unit segment along another side, altogether it consists of a quarter of a square.

Comment: This comes down to what context (i.e. mathematical object) multiplication takes place in. For example, multiplication is certainly repeated addition when dealing with the positive integers, but not so much when dealing with $3 \times 3$ matrices with complex-number entries (or even when just dealing with the complex numbers). That said, as @peterwhy points out, your repeated addition example is not correctly carried out.

Comment: @peterwhy wow that's stupid of me lol should I delete the post. Can't believe that I've missed that

Comment: As for multiplying fractions, $\dfrac{a}{b}\times \dfrac{c}{d} = \dfrac{a\times c}{b\times d}$ where here the multiplication within the numerator is the multiplication you are used to... similarly for the denominator.  We can then "simplify" the fractions as necessary, recalling what it means for two fractions to be equal.

Comment: *should I delete the post* --- Personally, I think your error might be worth having available for others to see in the future. Maybe you can answer your question, but you'll need to use correct math formatting in both the question and answer. However, I suspect others might downvote your question anyway (and perhaps also an answer, if you give one?), so maybe it's not worth it.

Comment: @JMoravitz I've actually already tried to read that post but I found the answers to complex.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro ok thanks. I'll look up correct formatting wasn't aware I was doing something wrong.

Comment: In your repeated addition scenario $\frac12 + \frac12$ is actually $2 \cdot \frac12$ which is why it equals $1$.

Comment: I formatted your post a bit. See [How can I format mathematics here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and the links given there for reference. In your case, dollar signs go around the separate math equations/expressions and the multiplication symbol's code is \times (the +, =, - signs are those on your keyboard).

Comment: Maybe you'll find [this analogy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4393149/0-5-times-0-5-equals-0-25-but-how-does-this-work-with-repeated-addition/4393163#4393163) useful?

Comment: This is a good question that already has answers. Related: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4187234/i-need-intuition-about-fraction-exponents-like-41-2-what-exactly-is-it/4187256#4187256 and 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2214839/exactly-how-does-the-equation-nn-1-2-determine-the-number-of-pairs-of-a-given/2214863#2214863